# Javascript submit.Jsp url parameters

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, servlets

I have internationalization at all of my jsp in web application. If url hasnt got any parameters it works ok ***(e.g. patient/bucket)***.
 But when i have something like `patient/order?action=registered` and change language url becomes equal to `/patient/order?language=ru`. 
So it deletes action paramter from url and i get nullPointer exception cause i need this parameter in my servlet. How can i save this parameter when changing lang?

```html
<form>
  <select id="language" name="language" onchange="submit()" style="margin-left: 50px">
    <option value="en" ${language == 'en' ? 'selected' : ''}>English</option>
    <option value="ru" ${language == 'ru' ? 'selected' : ''}>Русский</option>
    <option value="es" ${language == 'es' ? 'selected' : ''}>Español</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Comment: what happen when u get the current url and concat it with new url parameters?

Answer (score 0):

You must put a parameter on your form named "action":

```
<input type="hidden" name="action" id="action" value="registered">
```

Answer (score 0):

I think action parameter is passed from a servlet 
you can put this parameter as a value in an input hidden

```
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="${action}">
```